# disable window gridview get focus on first row

Tags: c#

Hi how do i disable the window gridview get focus on the first row?
i tried  `gvStudents.ClearSelection();` on the form load, but it did not do the trick.
please advice

Comment: You're calling ClearSelection() after the DataSource is set, correct?

Comment: If the GridView control has the input focus, *something* is going to be selected. There's no way around that. By default, that's the first cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling ClearSelection() in the DataBindingComplete event.

Answer (score 0):

in devexpress when you activate multi selection mode, it actually doesn't get focused to the first row, but instead it selects the first row. I had the same problem and have solved it by overriding the Onproperty changed event of the gridview .

```
      **protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{ base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
  this.ClearSelection();}
       }**
```