# Disable default cell selection in a datagridview after form load in WinForm Application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a dataGridView control in Window Form Application. Three columns are added to the dataGridView. I added 20 empty rows into dataGridView in order to show some blank cells.(Otherwise dataGridView just shows grey area).

On dataGridView control, I add three column "a","b", "c". In form load, I add this,

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(20);
```

after form initialize, datagridview shows some blank cell, but first cell in first row is selected(highlighted with blue color). **Please note, there is no data in datagridview.** I could not figure out how to clear the default selection.

I did some research. There are some discussion. I tried, ,and they were not working. I think it is because I don't have data in the control. But the method mentioned in the following link, is for a datagridview loaded with data.

[Disable default cell selection in datagridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209234/disable-default-cell-selection-in-datagridview)

[disable window gridview get focus on first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207999/disable-window-gridview-get-focus-on-first-row)

Also there are some discussion regarding Windows store application. (I am using windows form application)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1dc26694-1147-4d5b-8b7d-11c9c493e605/how-to-disable-default-selection-in-gridview-

[how to prevent autoselection of first item in GridView on databind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419606/how-to-prevent-autoselection-of-first-item-in-gridview-on-databind)

Thanks in advance if you can give me some ideas.

Comment: No. Setting the Selected property of the said cell to false works just fine without any data. If you don't succeed (and I remember having had weird problems with that last year) do this: Set it to true for another cell and then back to false. It will work, promise!

Comment: @Taw: Add this in form load : dataGridView3.Rows[0].Cells[0].Selected = false;  Not working. Then try this, dataGridView3.Rows[0].Cells[1].Selected = true; dataGridView3.Rows[0].Cells[1].Selected = false; Still no working. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Hm, I don't know. I think I set `MultiSelect` to false before and reset it afterwards..

Comment: @Taw: BTW, even I try             dataGridView3.Rows[0].Cells[0].Selected = false;
ataGridView3.Rows[0].Cells[2].Selected = true; Still the first cell in first row is selected...

Comment: @Taw: OK, it is working after I set MultiSelect to false.

Comment: Thanks, Taw. The final code are:            dataGridView3.Rows.Add(20);
dataGridView3.MultiSelect = false;
dataGridView3.Rows[0].Cells[2].Selected = true;
dataGridView3.Rows[0].Cells[2].Selected = false;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have used this code in my project's form's `Shown`-event:

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
```

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still having troubles with this I have found this worked for me when all the above suggestions failed.

On the DataGridView create an event for DataBindingComplete then add this method  datagridview1.ClearSelection();

Answer (score 2):

DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell.Selected = False

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce in a fresh test DGV but I have seen it before.

Here is what I found to work:

```
bool old = dataGridView1.MultiSelect;
dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Selected = true;
dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Selected = false;
dataGridView1.MultiSelect = old;
```

I don't know what causes this sometimes..
(..but I will add it to the answer once I do.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i got it working using this piece of code:

```
dataGridView1.EndEdit();
```

Hope this helps someone.